# wrong directory structure maven archetype-webapp using intellij

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am new in intellij IDE. I want to create a maven-archetype-webapp peoject But it does not create correct structure.Why?

I can't see same structure in this link.
http://javapointers.com/tutorial/creating-web-application-using-maven-in-intellij/
I am using Intellij IDE 14.0.1

Comment: http://www.tugay.biz/2013/10/hello-world-web-application-with-maven.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have successfully installed and tested maven in your local system. Make sure that you are using this maven to build project. You can check it from following path.

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Maven Home Directory
```

If not, change Maven directory to the local one and try to build again.(for directory name refer your tutorial link for maven windows installation).